# How to upload a file from a system directory to contiki file system (CFS)

Tags: contiki

I ve been working on contiki in sky mote. I am developing a system which does image processing in motes running in contiki. Since sky mote senses  temperature and light intensity, i cant upload an image to the mote. So im trying to upload a file from my hard drive to motes flash storage.
   I found out that dynamic link files can be uploaded using ELF uploader. But what i want to upload is a bmp file.